# How to change the source of an image with htaccess?

Tags: php, image, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've searched the site for an answer without success.

I would like to change `<img src="falsefolder/image.extension">` to
`<img src="images/image.extension">` with `.htaccess`.

So somebody taking a look at the `src` in inspector will see a false folder but in reality pull the image from images folder as the images are stored there.

The closest I could get to the solution was this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^falsefolder/(.*) images/$1 [L,R=301]
```

But it doesn't work at all. And yes, mod_rewrite is turned on in apache.

Is it even possible?

Comment: Why my image tags gets replaced.... anyways here we go again: src= "falsefolder/image.extension" to src="images/image.extension but I don't want to actually change the src, I just want to load images from images/ instead of falsefolder but in src show falsefolder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the **R** flag if you want to rewrite your image url.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^falsefolder/(.*) images/$1 [L]
```